# Replace text in div, paragraph using jQuery

Tags: jquery

How do I replace a text using jQuery as user types in the text box (in this case 'accoutnnumber')? I want to replace text '' with the number that was entered in textbox.

```
<input id="accoutnnumber" name="accoutnnumber" type="text">

<div id="divid">
    This is the Account: <replace with accountnumber>
</div>

<p id="divid">
    On my account (# <replace with accountnumber>) ......
</p>
```

Comment: Copy paste issue when I am coming up with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want elements with the same class, containing *just* the account number:

```
<input id="accountnumber" name="accountnumber" type="text">

<div id="divid">
  This is the Account: <span class="replaced"></span>
</div>

<p>
    On my account (<span class="replaced"></span>) ......
</p>
```

Fill those on `keyup` and `change` (so that pasting via the mouse, etc. still triggers the update):

```
$('#accountnumber').on('keyup change input',
  function() {
    $('.replaced').text($(this).val());
  }
 );
```

Example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/ofHux

Comment: Works great! How do make this work even if someone selects a auto fill text?

Comment: include the `input` event

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
$("#accoutnnumber").keypress(function() {
    $("#divid").text(this.value);
});
```

Also, ID's **must** be unique.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/dUgnk/

I modified your code a little bit for readability.  Also, IDs must be unique so I switched that as well.

HTML:

```
<input id="accountNumber" name="accountNumber" type="text">


<div id="divOne">
    This is the Account:
</div>

<div id="divTwo">
    On my Account: 
</p>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#accountNumber").keypress(function() {
    $("#divOne").text('This is the Account: ' + this.value);
    $("#divTwo").text('On my Account: ' + this.value);
});
```